# Displye IMEI in B4a

Tags: android, basic4android

I want Displaye IMEI in B4a 
but i have error in my code

Basic4android

```
Dim pi as PhoneId
Dim a as String
a=pi.GetDdeviceId
toastmessage(a,true)
```

basic4android

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: don't use IMEI. Because now Android Q (10) don't allow IMEI access

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling error when writing codes. Write like this:

```
Dim pi As PhoneId
Dim a As String
a=pi.GetDeviceId
ToastMessageShow(a,True)
```